# POST Request using CURL and PHP not working properly

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to programmatically process my statement using the form at http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process. I have the following code snippet in PHP/CURL. However, instead of processing the statement, it is returning the HTML for the form - as if the post parameters are not being sent.  I checked that I am sending the required paramaters. Can someone guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/14.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data  = array(
    'outputFormat' => 'xml',
    'input' => 'Here is a statement to process',
    'Process' => 'Submit Query'
     );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: have you replicated EVERYTHING about that form? cookies, referers, anti-spam hidden fields, etc...?

Comment: The submit button is not labelled `Submit Query`.

Comment: There are some cookies in the page, try to include them too

Comment: How do I add the cookies, referers etc ? Sorry I am new to CURL/PHP

Comment: For cookies - `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");` `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");` for Referrer  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.net");`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I made the suggested changes, still no luck:

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/14.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process");
    $data  = array(
        'outputFormat' => 'xml',
        'input' => 'Statement to process',
        'Process' => 'Submit Query'
         );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;

Comment: It returns the form from that site , rather than the output. When I submit the form manually, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the `$data` array into a string... Also, Be sure to `urlencode()` the individual values.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/14.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data  = array(
"outputFormat" => "xml",
"input" => "Here is a statement to process",
"Process" => "Submit Query"
 );

$data_string = "";

foreach($data as $key=>$value){ /// YOU HAVE TO DO THIS
$data_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';  /// AND THIS
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```